# preg_replace_callback with special character

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-replace-callback

I use php [preg-replace-callback](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-replace-callback.php) function to add link to part of string that is in an array :

```
<?php
$preg_quote_titles =  array('string 1 ? string 2 ?');

$content="string 1 ? string 2 ? string 3 ? ";

    $content = preg_replace_callback( '/(' . implode( '|', $preg_quote_titles ) . ')/i', function( $matches ) use ( $preg_quote_titles ) {

            return '<a href="#" class="post-link">' . $matches[0] . ' </a>';

    }, $content );


    echo $content;
    ?>
```

Code above doesn't work. Result is :

```
string 1 ? string 2 ? string 3 ?
```

With no link.

If I remove "?" character :

```
<?php
$preg_quote_titles =  array('string 1');

$content="string 1 ? string 2 ? string 3 ? ";

    $content = preg_replace_callback( '/(' . implode( '|', $preg_quote_titles ) . ')/i', function( $matches ) use ( $preg_quote_titles ) {

            return '<a href="#" class="post-link">' . $matches[0] . ' </a>';

    }, $content );


    echo $content;
    ?>
```

That works (links is added to "string 1")

How to include all character like parenthesis, question mark, etc ?

Comment: Hi! Please [edit] your question so that it's focussing on the specific part of the function you need help with. Do some debugging and break the problem down to a [mcve].

Comment: @IMSoP I have edit question by keeping only important part.

Comment: @Justinas Yes. preg_quote is the solution. Thanks !

Comment: Use `preg_quote()` on each of `$preg_quote_titles`